# Unable to boot/install any Mac OS/OS X system from/to SSD on my Macbook. Can't read any bootable USB device

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup, ssd

I've got a Macbook Pro Late 2012 with a Samsung EVO 750 and 16 gb of ram. I've worked with it for a year with no issues. Two weeks ago, it suddendly got really really slow (APFS on High Sierra). I couldn't even open the Apple Logo menu in order to shut it down or maybe logoff. It took like 2/3 minutes or more to open a Finder window. After some reboots the Dock couldn't even load the App Icons, question marks everywhere. So I decided to create a bootable High Sierra USB drive, backup my data first (with Paragon APFS for Windows) and then reinstall the system on the disk. Here come the troubles. It looks like once I booted the USB drive, the Macbook saves a flag in its cache, so that the second time I reboot the laptop and open up the Startup Menu there are no USB disks despite the fact they're plugged in. After waiting like 24 hours the "cache flag" looks like disappearing, so the Laptop sees the usb thumb again. After some tries I succeded in installing MacOS Sierra, but after some reboots (OS working) it suddendly got slow again. I reformated the SSD on my desktop pc with windows 10 and tested its speed with Samsung Magician and CrystalMark. 500 mb/s read and write, I don't think the disk is the problem. I thought the internal sata cable could have been damaged, but then I succesfully installed Sierra on an HDD and it works like a charm on the laptop. No way to get the SSD working. I'm pretty stuck. Thanks to anyone who would help!

Comment: Just a wild guess, and this may not be related to your issue at all, but years ago, I had an Intel SSD (this was when they weren't using their own controllers, iirc) and there was an EFI driver issue, that required me to boot into an older firmware using a restore disc, update the SSD firmware update, then re-update the firmware, wipe the drive, etc... Huge headache, but it fixed the issue. Are there firmware updates available for Samsung EVO's?

Comment: When I plugged it in to my PC and checked with Magician I found out it was up to date :(

Comment: ...wait a second. 2012 MacBook Pro did you say? Discrete graphics?

Comment: Yes. It’s a Late 2012 MacBook Pro 13”. Intel Graphics HD 4000, and 16 GB of ram. I don’t know if it may be some hardware’s fault. (I obviously updated my laptop in order to install a Samsung SSD and more ram)

Comment: Ah. Okay. Just curious though, do you have discrete graphics as well as the on package intel hd? Because if you do, it's most likely going to die on you any day now :/

Comment: No supplementary graphic cards on my laptop, just the Intel HD 4000. I hope there won't be any issue related to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the last non-retina MacBooks shipped with a SATA II drive cable if it came with a SATA II HDD. (Which makes sense because it shipped with a SATA II HDD... Not sure if it was different if you chose the Apple branded OEM SSD option, or if that was even an option for your model.)

You say you have a late 2012 MBP, but it must be either a late 2011 or mid 2012, to have user upgradable drives and memory, but I think this Is the case for both iterations.

So basically what I'm guessing is happening is that your MacBook and SSD are trying to communicate with each other at SATA III speeds, but over a SATA II cable.

[This cable](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2012-Hard-Drive-Cable/IF163-041-2) is compatible with SATA III, and replacement should fix your problem. To check if this really is the issue, you can try to use the SSD over any other interface (with an external FW, USB, Thunderbolt enclosure, for example) and see if the same issues exist. If not, the cable's probably the culprit.

Comment: I already tried to install and boot the system from/to the SSD with an external USB adapter (3.0 USB adapter). Looks like sometimes the speed decreases and the adapter causes "bottlenecks".
Anyway, there's another relevant problem: my laptop arbitrary reads USB devices on boot. So what I tried to do was: booting sierra from my working hdd, running the installation App and selecting the external SSD as destination. Once finished it boots again into the HDD without seeing the external plugged ssd, even If I open up the startup menu with the option key.

Comment: I'm considering the idea of buying a SATA Caddy in order to replace the disk drive with the SSD, so that both HDD and SSD are plugged via Sata and maybe I could succeed in finishing the installation correctly on my ssd.

Comment: @Halixness I’ve never liked the whole drive caddy instead of optical drive setup, but I’ve also had no experience using them either, so I can’t speak to its effectiveness. But the boot drive selection issue you describe is weird... are you doing a clean install, after wiping the drive with disk utility? I think GPT is the key thing, rather than MBR.

Comment: Yep, the SSD is already MacOS Journaled Extended with the GPT (GUID) scheme. I thought about the caddy thing because I guess that's the only way to test another SATA port and also make the SSD visible to the HDD and the system, so that it should install the system correctly... I'll let you know